# Kretschmann Scalar and Kruskal–Szekeres spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, singularities

One can use the Kretschmann Scalar to investigate curvature singularities, and in the case of Schwarzschild metric expressed using Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates or any other coordinates it is clear that the only singularity is at $r=0$, but I was wondering is there a "smart" way to calculate it, it seems to me that it would be a lot of work to compute it by hand and without using mathematica or similar tools.

Thanks for any insight or resources.

Comment: The Kretschmann Scalar does not "blow up" at Rs even in Schwartzschild cooridinates, so as far as I can tell there is no advantage in working it out in Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates.  Unless you just want an academic exercise, in which case you should do it "by hand" ;)

Comment: @m4r35n357 I get that, but I was wondering if I wanted to do it by hand, is there a way to do it without writing everything explicitly?

Comment: Not that I know of, I think it will be an uncheckable nightmare in KS coordinates (that implicit r), so good luck!  ;)